# An problem in elementary number theory used for proving Artin's lemma(class field theory)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I am confused by a following problem.

This is well-known for using in a proof of Artin reciprocity law, so I believe someone remember this.

**Problem.
Let $n=q_1^{r_1}\cdots q_s^{r_s}$ be the factorization of the integer $n$ as a product distinct primes and let $a>1$ be an integer.There exists infinitely many square-free integers $m=p_1\cdots p_sp_1'\cdots p_s'$ such that the order of $a\ \rm{mod}\ m$ is divisible by $n$.**

Please tell me a proof of this or answer to 
[Why as $r$ increases, prime $p$ s.t. $\operatorname{ord} a=q^r$ (in mod $p$) also increases?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3364220/682141).

But you can use the fact in the link above.

This fact also appears in Serge Lang "Algebraic Number Fields" p.201.

**Edit** Nancy Childress "Class Field Theory" p.116 avoides this trouble to prove Artin's lemma.

Comment: Assume $n=q$ is prime, if $p\ |\ a^{q^r}-1$, $p \ne q$ then $\frac{(a^{q^r})^{q^s}-1}{a^{q^r}-1}= \sum_{s=0}^{q^s-1} (a^{q^r})^s \equiv q^s \not \equiv 0 \bmod p$. Do the same for the remaining case $p=q$, from there you'll find infinitely many different primes $p_j$ dividing $a^{q^r}-1$ for some $r$ so that the order of $a \bmod p_j$ is $q^{s_j}$ with $s_j$ arbitrary large. The case $n$ composite reduces to doing the same with different $q$ and looking at the order of $a \bmod \prod_j p_j$.

Comment: @reuns Sorry could you explain in more detail? I don't understand what you're saying. Just in case, what I'm asking is not "$p\rightarrow \infty, then r\rightarrow \infty$" why but why "$r\rightarrow \infty, then p\rightarrow \infty$"(to be accurate, r<r' then p<p').

Comment: If it's possible, please answer in the link.